# How do I pin Thunderbird / Thunderbird Portable (and other stubbornly unpinnable programs) to my Windows 10 taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, thunderbird, taskbar, pinning

For most apps this is straightforward, as long as the app is running and showing on the taskbar, you simply right-click on the icon in the taskbar and a pin/unpin menu entry shows up.

However, lately, only "Write New Message" and "Open Address Book" and "Close Window" entries show up for Thunderbird.  None of all the other methods and advice out there helps or works.  Even manually creating a shortcut and copying it into

C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

then restarting Explorer.exe (or even Windows itself) DOES NOT WORK.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently there is this seemingly foolproof way to get this done.  Simply:

1. Pin a different program to the taskbar successfully
2. Right-click on its taskbar icon
3. Right-click again on that program's icon that shows up on the pop-up menu
4. Right-click on Properties, and now you see its Shortcut Dialog box
5. From there you can:

   a) Change the "Target" & "Start in" fields.

   b) Click on "Change icon" to switch the displayed icon to that of the formerly stubbornly unpinnable program one's.

That's it!  Do let us know if even this method doesn't work for you...